# Device interface over USB

Tags: window, usb

I have an usb device (pole display), which i don't have driver for.
I installed generic usb driver and opened the port for sending(I use bulk transfer) data to device.
With usb monitoring software i see my data gets to device, but nothing much happens on device side.
The device commands(ESC/POS) work when transfered over (virtual) com port, but not over usb port.

Shouldn't device process commands the same way regardless connection type (com vs usb)?
How can i figure out what commands work with the device (for example, if i send some text, i want it to show on display)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the USB descriptors the device reports in order to determine its class.  If it is a custom device and not a standard class then you'll likely not be able to work with it.  There is a big difference between old RS-232 COM protocol and USB.  USB devices can have multiple configurations and endpoints, each responding to data in different ways.  Many classes exist and are pretty standard (CDC-ACM is typically used for virtual serial ports.)  However, it's not uncommon for device manufacturers to include OEM specific configurations and endpoints which can be used for their own custom interfaces, firmware loading, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any initialization data transmitted through the COM port when connecting the device? The device surely can treat COM and USB different, but another possible thing that goes wrong is that the device needs to hear some sort of "I'm going to start sending commands"-signal from you first, and that signal may be different between COM and USB.

So what I would recommend is first (if you have not done that yet) see what data is sent to initialize the COM connection, and if that doesn't have an obvious USB counterpart, connect it to a PC where you do have drivers (assuming that is available somewhere and somehow, which is possible if e.g. you ask this due to OS incompatibility) and see how the connection is initialized there.

If the first doesn't work and the second is unavailable to you, then I'm afraid there's little I can do to help you, since it's usually not visible for you what commands the device wants to hear other than by guesswork, documentation, or comparing to similar devices where you do have that data available.